# Displaying data in <select> based on the value of another <select>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with two drop down menus, what I want to do is when an option is chosen in the first drop down menu based on the value chosen create an sql query that calls all rows where the value is equal and display the result in the second drop down menu.

My Code

```
    <form enctype = 'multipart/form-data' method = 'post' action = '' onChange='getManufacturer'>

    <tr>
        <td>Vehicle Manufacturer
      <select name = 'Manufacturer' id='M' onchange = "getModels(this.value)">
        <?php
                foreach($Manufacturers as $m)
        {?>
          <option value = '<?php echo $m['Manufacturer'] ?>'> <?php echo $m['Manufacturer'] ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
                <option Onclick="new_manufacturer()"> + Add New </option>
            </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Vehicle Model
            <select name = 'Model' id='MO'>
                <option Onclick="new_model()"> + Add New </option>
            </select> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</form
```

I have been thinking of using an onchange function and sending the value through ajax to get the values I want like this

Client Side

```
<script>
function getModels(Manufacturer){
    if(Manufacturer == "")
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getModels.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {Manufacturer: Manufacturer},
            //contentType: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Server Side

```
<?php
require('Vehicle_Type.php');
if(isset($_POST['Manufacturer']))
{
    require('connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT Models FROM vehicles
            WHERE Manufacturer = $_POST['Manufacturer']
            GROUP BY Models
    ";

    $rs = $db->query($sql);
    $db =null;
  }
    catch(PDOException $e){
      die($e->getMessage());
  }
}

?>
```

My problem is I don't know how to display the data I retrieve in the second drop down menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is to pass the result of your query back to a function that will populate the `select` element in your page. Your PHP code doesn't seem to be returning anything though.

In order to easily populate your element on the page, return a simple array.

```
while(($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))) {
        $Myarray[] = $row['Models'];
    }
}

echo json_encode($Myarray);
```

Also, change `success` to run the `pop_select` function below (or whatever name you like).

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'getModels.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {Manufacturer: Manufacturer},
            //contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {
                    myarray = JSON.parse(data);
                    pop_select(myarray);
            }
```

And here's how you'd populate the `select` element with the result of the call:

```
function pop_select(Myarray) {
var select = document.getElementById("Model");

for(i = 0; i < Myarray.length; i++) {
    var opt = Myarray[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the step by step answer but I seem to still have some issues and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `function getModels(Manufacturer){
 if(Manufacturer == "")
 {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'getModels.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {Manufacturer: Manufacturer},
   //contentType: false,
   success: function(data){
    Models = JSON.parse(data);
    pop_select(Models);
   }
  });
 }
}` `  foreach($rs as $r)
  {
    $Models[] = $r['Model']
  }

  echo json_encode($Models);
}`

Comment: `function pop_select(Models) {
var select = document.getElementById("Model");

for(i = 0; i < Models.length; i++) {
    var opt = Models[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
 }
}`

Comment: If it helps I have been getting this error in console log (SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data)

Comment: This error means that your data from the PHP code is not coming back as expected.Make sure that your PHP code is correct. One way to do this is to create a simple form that passes hard coded variables to the same `getModels.php` file. This way you can echo your variables and make sure that your query is returning the results you'd expect.

Comment: But wouldn't a form need a submit button to send variables to another page? I am probably not understanding exactly what you mean because I am still a it of a novice if you could edit your previous answer with an example on how to make sure my php code is correct that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, with a PHP file being called via Ajax it's hard to debug what's going on with your PHP code. If you create a quick HTML file with a form with the same names and fields you're passing to the PHP script you'd be able to `echo` variables like your query and query results, figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Managed to fix it and it is working fine now thank you very much. Another question if you don't mind, I would like to make it so if I change the value of the first drop down menu again it deletes the previously appended values to the second drop down menu.

Comment: Managed to solve that also. One last thing I would like that I am not sure how to do, since the function we are using is onChange it means the values will show only if I change the value but I would like it so that if the page loads with an already selected value to also call the function but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: You could add a script that runs when the page loads (jQuery or not) and if the value of that field is not empty (or other criteria that you define) you call the `pop_select()` function. Check [this link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)